# How to use a Spinner for filtering data in a fragment that taken from JSON

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, spinner

I have main activity and five fragment. In main activity I define toolbar. In each fragment I have a listview with data from JSON (I use volley labrary for fetch data from JSON).

**1**.   I want to filtering data using spinner, i.e with spinner I choose specific "city" and in my listview show only choosen listview items. So how do implement it?

**2**. All fragments take data from one JSON and there are all show similar data. I want to that when a spinner item seleced from some fragment it influence to other fragment, i.e. if in some fragment chosen "mycity" in other fragment have to show only listview item with "mycity". How to imlement it?

I try to do it,but ineffectually. Any ideas, helps are important for me. Sorry for bad English

[image: fragments]

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity   {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    //Checkong internet connect
    final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Проверьте соединение с интернотом" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Adding fragments to ViewPager
 * @param viewPager
 */
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new MainFragment(),"Все обьявления");
    adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "Нужен помощь" );
    adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "Потеряно" );
    adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "Найдено" );
    adapter.addFrag(new FourFragment(), "Отдам даром" );
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();



    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

MainFragment

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

// Log tag
private static final String TAG = "zhaksyadam";
public static String region="Алматы";
// Movies json url
private static final String url = "http://zhaksy-adam.kz/api/Requisitions/GetRequisition";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
Spinner spinner;

public MainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //adding spinner

    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vi = inflator.inflate(R.layout.spinnerwound, null);
    spinner = (Spinner) vi.findViewById(R.id.spin);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spinneradapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
            R.array.planets_array, R.layout.spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinneradapter);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(vi);


    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            region = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Log.d(TAG,"MainFragment:"+region);
            // Creating volley request obj
            final JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            hidePDialog();
                            if (movieList != null)
                                movieList.clear();
                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Movie movie = new Movie();

                                    String city_json = obj.getString("city");

                                    if (region.equals(city_json)) {
                                        String img = obj.getString("Picture1");
                                        if (img != null) {
                                            img = "http://zhaksy-adam.kz" + img;
                                            img = img.replace("~/", "/");
                                            img = img.replace(" ", "%20");
                                        }
                                        String date = obj.getString("Date");
                                        String[] s = date.split("T");

                                        movie.setTitle(obj.getString("Title"));
                                        movie.setThumbnailUrl(img);
                                        movie.setName(obj.getString("FullName"));
                                        movie.setYear(s[0]);
                                        movie.setRegion(obj.getString("region"));
                                        movie.setCity(obj.getString("city"));
                                        movie.setDescription(obj.getString("Description"));
                                        movie.setMobile(obj.getString("Phone1"));
                                        movie.setMail(obj.getString("E_mail"));
                                        movie.setType(obj.getString("type"));


                                        // adding movie to movies array
                                        movieList.add(movie);
                                    }

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }

                            // notifying list adapter about data changes
                            // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: to use a value cross app, you can use `SharedPreferences` to store and read this value,in this case the value is **the selected city** then you can filter the response (before adding `movie` to `movieList`) to check if `obj.getString("city")` equals value stored in `SharedPreferences`

Comment: @Yazan  As saliamu aleikum, may Allah be pleased with you. How do you think where  define a spinner in MainActivity or on each fragment? I try use define spinner on each fragment but it does't work.

Comment: walykom al salam bro, i think if it's a common value, no need for define in each fragment, you can make a fragment for app settings, where the user go and pick city, then you can read that value later on any fragment or activity, later you may need to add other settings to that screen, so it will be organized in one place

Comment: i mean if the value will be used in many places in the app, and it's **rarely** changed by user, then best place is a Settings screen

Comment: @yazan I did as you said and I arranged choosing city in Settings screen. How can I implement that list in fragment which at first shows  data from all city after choosing  by user shows  data from only one city.

Comment: you already have this in ur code, u just need to change where it comes from `if (region.equals(city_json)) {` now u need to compatre using Preferences value instead of variable `region` if user have selected a city,else, just fill list with the wholes response from server

Comment: @yazan i did as you said but how to reload list after choosing

Comment: clear the data arrayList, notifiy the adapter, look you need to read about ListView and Adapters

Comment: @yazan thank you bro